# How can I execute different catches depending on which side I am out of bounds?

Tags: c++, exception, try-catch

I've overloaded an operator such that I can return the value of an array. I can handle out of bounds using `if`:

```
float arr::operator[](const int i) const
{
    if (i < 0)
    {
        cout << "Outside of array, first entry returned" << endl;
        return value[0];
    }

    else if (i >=size)
    {
        cout << "Outside of array, last entry returned"  << endl;
        return value[size-1];
    }

    else return value[i];
}
```

but I am learning about exceptions and try-catch blocks.

Is it possible to throw an exception with a different int (for example) for out of upper/lower bounds, and have catches that execute different code depending on the value of that int?

I know that `if`  works well here, but I'm looking to develop my knowledge for use in more complex ideas.

Comment: Don't throw integers.  Throw a _type_.

Comment: Ah yes, I considered this, but it feels clunky? Throw an int for below bounds and a string for above? Is this the best solution?

Comment: Not clunky at all and instantly recognizable to anyone reading your code. Name the type correctly and the code is almost self documenting. A programmer who sees `throw 42;` is likely to have a WTF moment followed by searching through the code trying to figure out what you are doing or the same WTF moment followed tossing your code into a waste bin. But if they see `throw lowerbound;`, that tells them something.

Comment: Why you don't throw directly `std::out_of_range` ?

Comment: @raindrop7 As far as I could see it didn't differentiate low and high, just that it was out of bounds.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is it possible to throw an exception with a different int (for example) for out of upper/lower bounds, and have catches that execute different code depending on the value of that int?

Sort of.  You can certainly throw a different `int` value based on a condition, but you would have to catch a single generic `int` and test its value, you can't catch different `int` values individually. For example:

```
const int OutOfBoundsInFront = -1;
const int OutOfBoundsInBack = 1;

float arr::operator[](const int i) const
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw OutOfBoundsInFront;

    if (i >= size)
        throw OutOfBoundsInBack;

    return value[i];
}

...

try
{
    ... = myarr[index];
}
catch (int value)
{
    switch (value)
    {
        case OutOfBoundsInFront:
            //...
            break;

        case OutOfBoundsInBack:
            //...
            break;
    }
}
```

However, when throwing an exception, it is better to throw an object instead of a simple POD type.  `catch` blocks deal in types, not values.  In this case, you can define different class types for each condition you want to catch. For example:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class OutOfBoundsInFront : public std::out_of_range
{
public:
    OutOfBoundsInFront() : std::out_of_range("out of bounds in front") {}
};

class OutOfBoundsInBack : public std::out_of_range
{
public:
    OutOfBoundsInBack() : std::out_of_range("out of bounds in back") {}
};

float arr::operator[](const int i) const
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw OutOfBoundsInFront();

    if (i >= size)
        throw OutOfBoundsInBack();

    return value[i];
}

...

try
{
    ... = myarr[index];
}
catch (const OutOfBoundsInFront &)
{
    //...
}
catch (const OutOfBoundsInBack &)
{
    //...
}
```

Alternatively:

```
#include <stdexcept>

class OutOfBoundsOnSide : public std::out_of_range
{
public:
    enum WhichSide { InFront, InBack };

    static const char* WhichSideErrorMsg[] = {
        "out of bounds in front",
        "out of bounds in back"
    };

    WhichSide whichSide;

    OutOfBoundsOnSide(WhichSide side) : std::out_of_range(WhichSideErrorMsg[side]), whichSide(side) {}
};

class OutOfBoundsInFront : public OutOfBoundsOnSide
{
public
    OutOfBoundsInFront() : OutOfBoundsOnSide(InFront) {}
};

class OutOfBoundsInBack : public OutOfBoundsOnSide
{
public
    OutOfBoundsInBack() : OutOfBoundsOnSide(InBack) {}
};

float arr::operator[](const int i) const
{
    if (i < 0)
        throw OutOfBoundsInFront();

    if (i >= size)
        throw OutOfBoundsInBack();

    return value[i];
}

...

try
{
    ... = myarr[index];
}
catch (const OutOfBoundsOnSide &e)
{
    switch (e.whichSide)
    {
        case InFront:
            //...
            break;

        case InBack:
            //...
            break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, this seems to be an excellent answer! Several solutions building in complexity. I just learnt a lot! (Also, you were always my favourite of the X-Men ;)  )